# nuxt application is not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, polyfills

I have the nuxt application which works fine in chrome and all other browser but it is getting failed in the internet explorer.

I tried so many solutions on the internet but had no luck yet so asking for help from someone who got in the same problem while supporting the internet explorer.

Below are my nuxt.config and package.json.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    head: {
        title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
        meta: [{
                charset: 'utf-8'
            },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
            }
        ],
        link: [{
            rel: 'icon',
            type: 'image/x-icon',
            href: '/favicon.ico'
        }],
        script: [{
            src: 'https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=es5,es2015,Array.from,es6,Object.entries,Object.defineProperty,IntersectionObserver,gated&flags=gated&unknown=polyfill&callback=onPolyfillsLoad'
        }]
    },
    /*
     ** Customize the progress-bar color
     */
    loading: {
        color: '#fff'
    },
    /*
     ** Global CSS
     */
    css: [
        
    ],
    /*
     ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
     */
    plugins: [],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
     */
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
        '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
        // '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/stylelint-module
        // '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module'
    ],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js modules
     */
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/proxy',
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
        'cookie-universal-nuxt',
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
    ],
    bootstrapVue: {
        components: ['BTabs', 'BTab']
    },
    axios: {
        proxyHeaders: true,
        init(axios, ctx) {
            axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;'
        }
    },
    env,
    /*
     ** Build configuration
     */
    build: {
        transpile: [],
        vendor: ['axios'],
        /*
         ** You can extend webpack config here
         */
        extend(config, ctx) {

        }
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "repo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "repo",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "lint": "eslint - ext .js,.vue - ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint - fix - ext .js,.vue - ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint:css": "stylelint - fix ./**/*.{vue,scss,css}"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.{js,vue}": "npm run lint:fix",
        "*.{css,vue}": "npm run lint:css"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "⁴.5.2",
        "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "¹.4.0",
        "@nuxtjs/proxy": "².0.1",
        "@nuxtjs/pwa": "³.0.0–0",
        "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "¹.11.3",
        "axios": "⁰.21.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "².21.2",
        "cookie-universal-nuxt": "².1.4",
        "cross-env": "⁵.2.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "⁸.5.1",
        "lodash": "⁴.17.20",
        "moment": "².29.1",
        "nuxt": "².0.0",
        "vuex-persist": "³.1.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "².0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "¹.0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "³.1.0",
        "babel-eslint": "¹⁰.0.1",
        "eslint": "⁶.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "⁶.2.2",
        "eventsource-polyfill": "⁰.9.6",
        "lint-staged": "¹⁰.0.0",
        "node-sass": "4.14.0",
        "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
        "stylelint": "¹⁰.1.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "²⁰.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "nuxt": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0"
        }
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "¹⁰.x"
    }
}
```

Error:
which I am getting after so many changes,

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
testpage
polyfill-eventsource added missing EventSource to window
[HMR] connected
SCRIPT5078: Cannot redefine non-configurable property 'values'
polyfill.js (3,2023)
```

[image]

Kindly help me to figure out how I can debug or fix this thing so I can run the nuxt application in the internet explorer.

Comment: is it a runtime error or a compile time error?

Comment: Now that your project is done, you will have the most work to debug all of this. First question: which version of IE is it and do you really need to support IE nowadays? (check the usage stats) Second, do you have a [repro]? Third: can you narrow down the issue? What is buggy exactly? Try to comment out things to find out what exactly errors.

Comment: @Bravo it is run time error.

Comment: @kissu yes I will start doing that today. Do you know any solution by adding babel in the build? I have seen some answers but never tried

Comment: Depends of the issue and the targeted browsers.

Comment: It is only happens in internet explorer 11

Comment: @app - lucky that browser is no longer relevant - why do you care? is it essential?

Comment: Yes, my client is still using it.. :(